# Issue with where clause in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to get course details based on instructorid. User can select multiple instructor at time. so i gave instructor ID as a nvarchar value ( '1000,1001,1002' etc..) . The expected ouptut is, when i give instructor id is null then all the records need to be returned ( no filtering) else records need to be returned for the given instructorid . so i have tried out below ways.           I have created a function to get instructorid as a table.  then i executed below query.

```
select *from class c
where c.InstructorID  in 
(case  when @InstructorID is null then c.InstructorID else  
        (select value from #instructors)   end)
```

(#instructor is the table which hold instructor id's) .  But i got an error while executing the stored procedure.  " Sub query returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the sub query follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the sub query is used as an expression."  why this error comes? any other way to execute the same query?

Comment: #instructors table contains multiple values (all the comma separated instructor id's)

Comment: Ideally, change the table structure. SQL Server has two types **designed** for holding multiple values - XML and tables themselves. Note that "strings that happen to contain commas" wasn't on that list.

Comment: the query should retrieve the records for all the instructor ids in  
#instructors table. if @instructorid is null then it should retrieve all the records in the table.

Comment: E.g. [Table-Valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) allows you to pass multiple instructor values *as* a table.

Comment: the structure is like this                                                                                      value                                                                                                                                      1001
1002
2003

Comment: I know full well what the structure is, I can take it from the question. What I'm recommending is to **change** the structure, because it's *not* a natural way to represent multiple values in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Use this way:

```
where @InstructorID is null OR c.InstructorID  in (select value from #instructors)
```

However, i'm not sure where you're using the parameter `@InstructorID` to filter at all.

Comment: I think @InstructorID is comma separeted string that he extracts into #instructors.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: I agree. But hopefully OP knows how to use it in his query. My poins is that he should not use the `NULL`-check with `CASE` in the `IN`-clause but before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use max or min function. Try this query

```
select *from class c where c.InstructorID in (case when @InstructorID is null then c.InstructorID else (select max(value) from #instructors) end)
```

Comment: Hi need all the values from #instructor table.not the maximum only. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add Order and TOP 1 in your subquery to return only one Row like this

```
select TOP 1 value from #instructors order by value desc
```

Comment: Hi need all the values from #instructor table.not the maximum only. thanks

Comment: in this case you should use advice by @Tim Schmelter its just a simple way how to avoid more then 1 record from a subquery

Comment: LIMIT is a MySql convention and this is clearly not tagged with MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way to code the scenario you describe. Take into consideration to avoid the addition of complexity to your code where is not really needed.

```
IF (@InstructorID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Class c
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Class c
    WHERE   InstructorID = @InstructorID
END
```

Other best practices:

1. Take into consideration to display a discrete list of columns instead of the
   usage of '*' to improve performance.
2. The use of indentation and uppercase for SQL-reserved words are best practices that will make your code easier to read and understand